# Is this a valid way to return a pointer to a value in a map?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have come across this code, and I'm not sure whether or not it is safe.

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename C>
const V* Find(const std::map<K, V, C>& map, const K& path)
{
    auto iter = map.find(path);
    if (iter != map.end())
    {
        return &iter->second;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

It is being used on this object:

```
    std::map<std::pair<std::wstring, bool>, std::pair<std::vector<std::wstring>, std::map<std::wstring, bool, CaseInsensitiveStringLessThan>>, CaseInsensitiveTargetCacheLessThan> m_paths;
```

And the comparer is the following:

```
    struct CaseInsensitiveStringLessThan : public std::binary_function<std::wstring, std::wstring, bool> {
    bool operator()(const std::wstring& lhs, const std::wstring& rhs) const {
        if (lhs.length() == rhs.length())
        {
            // Paths in the same process tend to share a significant prefix in common. Starting backwards
            // has a better chance to hit a difference first
            auto result = std::lexicographical_compare(rhs.rbegin(), rhs.rend(), lhs.rbegin(), lhs.rend(),
                [](const wchar_t a, const wchar_t b) { return towlower(a) < towlower(b); });
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return lhs.length() < rhs.length();
        }
    }
    };
```

I am concerned on whether the pointer returned by Find() is valid, or whether it ceases to be valid once the Find method exits.  In particular, I am discovering that some values I am getting back from `m_paths` are corrupt, and I'm trying to figure out why.  I know they are not corrupt when I add them to the map via:

```
    m_paths[std::make_pair(path, true)] = std::make_pair(insertion_order, resolved_paths);
```

But when I search for them later, `insertion_order` and `resolved_paths` are both pointing to invalid memory sometimes.  If Find() is the issue, what is way to fix it?  Should I be storing pointers in the map instead of the pairs?

Comment: `m_paths[std::make_pair(path, true)] = std::make_pair(insertion_order, resolved_paths);` Sometimes map may not have memory for above statement to work. Try with m_paths.insert and see if the error resolves

Comment: Yes, `return &iter->second;` is fine. `iter->second` provides the value for the key/value and taking its address provides a valid pointer to that memory location.

Comment: How do I deal with overwriting existing values if I use insert though?

Comment: You can use `find` first to check if it's existing. If it's there use the `m_paths[..] = .. ;` , else use `insert`

Comment: Also, what happens if you erase the value from the map after you call this Find?  Does the pointer stay valid?  I'm guessing not.

Comment: @Wander3r always 2 lookups instead of one, brilliant idea.

Comment: Pointer is fine as that object exists (neither object removed nor map destroyed). Otherwise impossible to say, not enough information. It is not clear what are `insertion_order` and `resolved_paths`

Comment: The pointer remains valid until the key is removed from the map, or the map is destroyed.

Comment: Would this work?
            auto found = m_paths.emplace(std::make_pair(normalizedPath, preserveLastReparsePointInPath), std::make_pair(insertion_order, resolved_paths));
            if (!found.second)
            {
                found.first->second = std::make_pair(insertion_order, resolved_paths);
            }

My current guess would be that something is updating the value in another thread while the first thread has the result of the find.  When I use emplace, I don't see the error, but neither does it update the value.